# How to get nid by row click in GridView only through javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, gridview, onclick

I have a situation where i have a GridView haveing mutiple rows and columns whicha re binded well and display data in them. The code is like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="dgnews" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    OnRowCommand="dgnews_RowCommand"  OnPageIndexChanging="dgnews_PageIndexChanging"
    OnRowDataBound="dgnews_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S.No."  ItemStyle-Width="15px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Transfer Date" SortExpression="assetcode" ItemStyle-Width="15%">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "transferdate")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>                                      

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Department" ItemStyle-Width="18%">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "departmentname")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="5px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnedit" Visible="false" CommandName="edititem" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("nid")%>'
                    ToolTip="Edit" runat="server"><i class="fa fa-fw" ><img src="images/edit.png" alt="" /></i></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>   
    </Columns>                                                    
</asp:GridView>
```

And i have handled dgnews_RowCommand in my c# code by doing soemthing liek this:

```
protected void dgnews_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "edititem")
    {
        Value = e.CommandArgument.ToString();// And i get the value of id of clicked row link button like this
    }
}
```

And i get the value of nid of link button clicked like this `"Value = e.CommandArgument.ToString();"` . It works fine.

Now what i want is to get this nid on a row click in this grid view just by javascript onclick function call. I mean, when i click a row it must call a function `onclick="displayHistoryThroughImages(#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,'nid'));"`  at  this line:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="dgnews" runat="server" OnRowCommand="dgnews_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="dgnews_RowDataBound"onclick="displayHistoryThroughImages(#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,'nid'));">
```

and in javascript i must get it's nid liek this:

```
<script>
function displayHistoryThroughImages(nid)
{
    alert("row pressed with nid : "+nid );
}
</script>
```

But it do not work. How to make it work ? I mean i click a row and it must call the function displayHistoryThroughImages() with the nid of that row and only in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Just try too change onclick to this one

```
onclick='<%#  "javascript:displayHistoryThroughImages('" + Eval("nid") +"')" %>'
```

**JS Function:**

```
function displayHistoryThroughImages(nid)
            {

                alert("row pressed with nid : "+nid );
            }
```

Comment: it also gives error in c# code :Error 15 The name 'dgnews' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @testtest u need to assign the onclick to LinkButton,but not to the grid, here we need to get the id of the row that's being clicked, when you do on gridview, you wont get that id

Comment: But in my situation i have to get nid by clicking that row (not by clciking that link button). Do you have any solution for it ?